# Weird internet connection behavior

Tags: internet, internet-connection

I'm having a strange problem with my internet connection.

At the moment my ISP is Fastweb (an italian provider) and i noticed that sometimes i can't load some sites, then all i have to do is wait 5 minutes and then i can load the site again. Some other times, instead, images won't load on certains sites (this always happens with 500px.com or Facebook rarely).

I noticed that if i use VPN software like [Privitize VPN](http://privitize.com/) or [Spotflux](http://www.spotflux.com/) everything works like a charm.

Is something wrong with my internet configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a different DNS provider.  Using a VPN often means you start using the VPN's DNS configuration depending HOW you connect to the VPN.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work setting Google DNS.

Comment: Your ISP is running some sort of proxy that causes this problem. I would complain to service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your ISP operates a transparent HTTP proxy and it gets overloaded from time to time.

If you don't experience this issue with HTTPS then this is very likely.

Nothing you can do really except switch ISPs or continue to use VPNs.